# Call Graph API from MVC App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

SUMMARY UPDATE:
I got a sample working today thanks to the many good replies. Thanks all. My primary goal was to get current user information (ME) without using secret key. First I just used the secret key from the App Reg and this will authenticate the App and not the user. This does of course not work when calling ME. My next finding was if you want the users token, you still need the App Reg token, and then you request the users token. This requires less permissions on the App Reg, but requires to request two tokens. I ended up skipping ME and just requesting information for a specified user (through the APp Reg permissions):

```
$"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{email}/$select=companyName"
```

Both both approaches should be viable. I updated code below with working sample.

---

I am trying to do a very simple call to graph API to get companyName from current user. Found some samples but they seemed to be very complicated. The MVC app is authenticated trough an Application Registration in AAD.

I guess the application registration needs to be authorized to access Graph API. Or is more needed here? Getting company name should be fairly simple:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=companyName
```

Does anyone have a snippet for calling the graph API, my best bet would be you need to extract a bearer token from the controller? ALl help is appreciated.

Working snippet:

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {

           string clientId = "xxx";
        string clientSecret = "xxx";

        var email = User.Identity.Name;

        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token");
        ClientCredential creds = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", creds);

        HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
        string url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{email}/$select=companyName";
        //url = "https://graph.windows.net/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6";

        // Append the access token for the Graph API to the Authorization header of the request by using the Bearer scheme.
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request);
        var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I have a sample that calls the Graph API here: https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth. Though it is for ASP.NET Core, the basic principles are the same.

Comment: You could take a look at [HowTo: invite AAD user with Microsoft Graph](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/invite-aad-user-microsoft-graph/). It's a simple guide on how to invite users. Getting data for the current user is 'just' using delegate permissions and getting `GraphServiceClient.Me`

Comment: For both of your samples it requires a secret password added in the application registration. Is this needed when you only want to get your own properties?

Comment: These are not your own properties. They are the user's properties. Unless you authenticate the user and pass that token to the API, the API will have no idea who "me" is or where to look.

Comment: But the user is authenticated through the MVC application are you saying this is not enough? I was thinking getting the bearer from the MVC app and send it with the call to Graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add one last item, here is a link to an MVC sample on Git that uses an MVC application to send email.  It illustrates how to call the MS Graph API to get various pieces of information.  Keep in mind, if you are using an application only scenario, ME will not work, the sample illustrates how to obtain a delegated token for a user and use that toke to do work:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-rest-sample

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this code snippet correctly, You are requesting a application only token for the Graph.Microsoft.Com resource, then attempting to use that toke with this URI:
url = "https://graph.windows.net/thomaseg.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6"

This will not work because you are mixing resources, AAD Graph and MS Graph.  The ME endpoint does not make since in this scenario because you are using the application only flow.  This flow does not support the ME endpoint.  ME is designed for use with a delegated token.  the ME endpoint represents the signed in user, since and application is not a user, ME is meaningless.

You will need to target the user specifically:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/[UPN or ID of user]?$select=companyName

Should work if your application has been granted the appropriate permission scopes.